# Can you explain about the proper combination of verb with noun in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, zero-article

[Source](http://www.pressreader.com/india/the-times-of-india-new-delhi-edition/20160423/282282434480991)

This was a statement I read in the Times of India newspaper about Purple Prince:

> He rocked a braggadocio guitar and spandex and eyeliner and a feminine ache and a chest full of hair and, high heels and a proud blackness and basically magic.

I think there's a misuse of a comma.

He rocked:
a guitar
a spandex
and an eyeliner

There may be a 'had' missing over there.He **had**:
a feminine ache and
a chest full of hair

Then 'high heels and a proud blackness and basically magic.'I could not get it right meaning.

Also are the articles missing with 'spandex' and 'eyeliner' , 'high heels' while they have been used repeatedly in 'a feminine' and 'a chest', 'a proud'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us examine the definition of *rock* here.

> [rock](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rock?s=t)
>   11. b. to use, wear, or display in a showy, self-confident manner or to great effect:
>   *Only you could rock that hat!*

Here is a list of things that Prince did (according to the author):

1. He rocked a braggadocio guitar.
2. He rocked spandex.
3. He rocked eyeliner.
4. He rocked a feminine ache.
5. He rocked a chest full of hair
6. He rocked high heels.
7. He rocked a proud blackness.

So Prince wore/displayed these these things in a showy manner.
It sounds awkward to me, but Prince "rocked basically magic", could mean that he was (basically) able to wear/display magic. I would take this to imply that he was magical.

So, instead of listing a list as I listed above, the author squeezes it all together in one sentence. I would say that this is a deliberate, rhetorical decision made by the author. The effect is to give you the impact of how great/interesting/quirky Prince was. So I don't believe it is a "misuse" of commas. Instead, I would say it is an *advanced* way to omit commas.

So, you could break up the sentence and say

> He had a feminine ache and a chest full of hair.

But that doesn't have the same feeling as the original sentence.

Number 7 means that he showed pride in being black (African-American). He wore/rocked his blackness with pride. This is figurative speech since one does not wear their skin color.